# Apache VirtualHost config doesnt redirect how i need it to

Tags: apache, config, virtualhost

The problem is why does this redirect http://www.example.com to https://example.com and why doesn't https://example.com redirect to https://www.example.com? I want to redirect everyone to https and to www. I have tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to fix this.

```
/etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    RedirectMatch ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    RedirectMatch ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests.log combined
    SLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/chain.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conf.d/non-ssl.conf was incorrect :D